# How to execute certain command on Windows program?

Tags: python, image, automation, operating-system, save-as

So I am opening an SVG file in a program called Inkspace using a script with the `os` and `subprocess` package. Once I have opened this file in Inkspace I would like to click save as or some how save as for the image in Inkspace using python. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is possible. Before closing Inkscape, you need to call Inkscape command for exporting your file via python.

I think something like this will do the job.

```
import subprocess

# Your current stuff.
# Save the working file before closing Inkscape.
subprocess.run(["inkscape", "--export-type=\"png\"", "my_file.svg"])
```

You can look at the following link for Inkscape command line interface:
[Inkscape CLI help](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Using_the_Command_Line)
or type the following in the windows shell to see available commands.

```
inkscape --help
```